# How do I get Spring generated cookies to expire when browser is closed?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot

A Spring Boot app has REST services that set cookie values inside a Spring Controller and then send the cookies out to the client in the response using `HttpServletResponse` as follows:

```
response.addCookie(new Cookie("AUTH1", "no"));
```

But when I close firefox, then re-open firefox and call the app's url again, the cookie values are exactly the same.  **How can I make sure that cookie values are destroyed when the browser closes, so that the cookies do not exist when the browswer is re-opened?**  Can this be configured in the Spring Boot app?  Or do I need to configure it in the front end app?

---

**ONGOING EFFORTS:**

Changing all the `response.setCookie()` lines in the backend REST controller to `session.setAttribute()` lines for the same key value pairs did not produce anything that the AngularJS client app could read using `$cookies.get('keyname')` even though they were the same key names.  **Is there a way to set session cookies in Spring controllers that will automatically be destroyed when the user closes their browser?**

I also tried to implement `@shazin`'s suggestion by using a method (because cookies are recreated many times in the controller class), but the problem is only partially resolved.  Specifically, I took the following steps:

1.) I started with a couple of browser windows open, only one of which contained the app being tested.
2.) I changed all the code as shown below,
3.) then I killed the app with control-C and also killed the process running on the port.
4.) Then I `mvn clean package`
5.) and then I start up the app again with `java -jar jarname`, and load it up in a new InPrivate browser window.
6.) I use the logout method to remove any cookies that might have lingered from previous versions,
7.) then I use the GUI to trigger new cookie definitions, which work as intended.
8.) But then I test by closing the browser window that contains the app being tested and then re-opening a new browser window and navigating to the site again, **but the cookie values are still there, so this approach has not solved the problem.**
9.) Finally, I closed both open browser windows (each browser window has a few tabs of its own open.  After closing all the browser windows, I opened a new browser window, and found that the cookies had been removed.  **So the approach below only works if you close ALL open browser windows and not just the browser window containing the app.**

Here is the method that I wrote to implement @shazin's suggestion:

```
public Cookie getTempCookie(String key, String val){
    Cookie tempCookie = new Cookie(key, val);
    tempCookie.setMaxAge(-1);
    return tempCookie;
}
```

And here is how I call the method from the various url pattern handlers inside the controller:

```
response.addCookie(getTempCookie("AUTH1", "yes"));
```

**What else can I do to get the cookies to be deleted when only the window containing the app gets closed?**  In its present form, there is still a security risk if a user closes their browser window without realizing that another browser window is still opened.

Answer (score 6):

What you can do is set Max Age of the Cookie to -1 which will not persist the cookie and will delete when the browser closes.

```
Cookie authCookie = new Cookie("AUTH1", "no");
authCookie.setMaxAge(-1);
response.addCookie(authCookie);
```

Javadoc for Max Age says the following

```
A negative value means that the cookie is not stored persistently and will be deleted when the Web browser exits. A zero value causes the cookie to be deleted.
```

Comment: I added a section to the end of the OP with results of trying your suggestion.  Your approach is only partially successful.  Thank you and +1 for taking the time to help move this forward.  Are you able to suggest a more complete solution?